# UIButton's titleLabel.text is not displayed on Cocoa Touch

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, ios

After I create a new UIButton at runtime, and set its titleLabel's text, the button's text is still not displayed.

What am I doing wrong?

```
-(IBAction) cloneMe: (id) sender{

    if (!currentY) {
        currentY = [sender frame].origin.y;
    }

    UIButton *clone = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    CGRect cloneFrame = [sender frame];
    cloneFrame.origin.y += currentY + cloneFrame.size.height + 30;
    clone.frame = cloneFrame;
    [clone titleLabel].text = @"I'm a clone";

    [[sender superview] addSubview:clone];

    currentY = cloneFrame.origin.y + cloneFrame.size.height;


}
```

Comment: Is the cloned button itself showing up?

Comment: Yes, it's just the text that doesn't show up.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need:

```
[clone setTitle:@"I'm a clone" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Check out the `UIControl` API docs for other valid values for the `forState:` argument.

Answer (score 2):

Use `setTitle:forState:` to set the title of a button.